# Maintain order while sorting groupby using alternative methods?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, sorting, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to sort a groupby but I’m having a little trouble getting it exactly how I want and as I explore "groupby" I just come up with more questions.
Anyway, let me set the groundwork. We have this dataset:

```
                  Name     Role  Cost  Value  
0       Johnny Tsunami   Driver  1000     39
1   Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
2           Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
3         Greg Ritcher  Lookout   200     25
4       Johnny Tsunami   Driver  1000     39
5   Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
6           Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
7          Appa Derren  Lookout   250     30
8          Baby Hitsuo   Driver   950     35
9   Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
10          Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
11         Appa Derren  Lookout   250     3
```

Essentially I want the groups to be sorted in descending order by the sum of the Values in each groupby and placed back into a dataframe in that order.

The groupby essential splits each group into 4s:

```
0
                 Name     Role  Cost  Value
0      Johnny Tsunami   Driver  1000     39
1  Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
2          Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
3        Greg Ritcher  Lookout   200     25
```

Value: 160

```
1
                 Name     Role  Cost  Value
4      Johnny Tsunami   Driver  1000     39
5  Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
6          Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
7         Appa Derren  Lookout   250     30
```

Value: 165

```
2
                  Name     Role  Cost  Value
8          Baby Hitsuo   Driver   950     35
9   Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
10          Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
11         Appa Derren  Lookout   250     30
```

Value: 161

This is what I want the end dataframe to be:

```
4       Johnny Tsunami   Driver  1000     39
5   Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
6           Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
7          Appa Derren  Lookout   250     30
8          Baby Hitsuo   Driver   950     35
9   Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
10          Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
11         Appa Derren  Lookout   250     30
0       Johnny Tsunami   Driver  1000     39
1   Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
2           Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
3         Greg Ritcher  Lookout   200     25
```

The Problem is.... this is a just small sample of a 10000 row dataset. It works when I sort the small sample set but when I sort the massive list, the sort doesn't maintain the Driver, Pistol, Pistol, Lookout order. It comes out mixed up per group like Pistol Driver Pistol Lookout. I want to maintain the Role order after the sort.
Lets run down what I have tried.
I've tried:

Tried sorting like below:

```
grp = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index))//4)
grp[['Value']].transform(sum).sort('Value')
sort1 = df.loc[grp[['Value']].transform(sum).sort_values('Value').index]
```

Tried doing this with a Key instead of Value as well.

Creating a key and sorting it by the keys:

```
df['key']=df['Value'].groupby(np.arange(len(df))//4).transform('sum')
df=df.sort_values('key',ascending=False)
```

Also I believe the sort on groupby is automatically set to true, I played with turning that to false and true still not correct.

Its fine until the sort happens it seems the groupby maintains the order up until the sort.

Is there a way to hard specify I want the sort order to be exactly Driver, Pistol, Pistol, Lookout, or if I can figure out the order I want the groups in as such

```
gr = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index.values))//4)
grp_order = (gr.sum()).sort_values('Value', ascending=False).index
```

is there a way to use grp_order to tell the groupby ("while its still grouped") to reaarange themselves in the dataframe according to the grp_order thats the only thing I could think of.

If possible could we avoid for loops the dataset may get larger I want the speed to be as fast as possible. Been beating my brain silly for weeks trying to figure out where I'm going wrong at.

Comment: I don't see the issue with your method that defines `key` and then sorts based on that; it is correct. `.groupby` does not change the sorting order within group. If it did, methods like `.diff`, `.cumsum` and `.cumcount` would be entirely useless. The docs specifically state `groupby preserves the order of rows within each group.` If the ordering is not `Driver Pistol Pistol Lookout` in your output, it's because that is not the case before you groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) as it is guaranteed to preserve order within each group, This bit of information is tucked away under the `sort` parameter in the docs

> sort : boolean, default True
>
> Sort group keys. Get better performance by turning this off. **Note this
>   does not influence the order of observations within each group.
>   groupby preserves the order of rows within each group.**

Since the output is not Driver Pistol Pistol Lookout ordering, your underlying DataFrame is not sorted like that for every group. Define another key, and sort based on two keys:

```
df['key'] = df.groupby(df.index.values//4).Value.transform(sum)
df['key2'] = df.Role.map({'Driver': 1, 'Pistol': 2, 'Lookout': 3})

df = df.sort_values(['key', 'key2'], ascending=[False, True])
```

#### Output:

```
                  Name     Role  Cost  Value  key  key2
4       Johnny_Tsunami   Driver  1000     39  165     1
5   Michael_B._Jackson   Pistol  2500     46  165     2
6           Bobby_Zuko   Pistol  3000     50  165     2
7          Appa_Derren  Lookout   250     30  165     3
8          Baby_Hitsuo   Driver   950     35  161     1
9   Michael_B._Jackson   Pistol  2500     46  161     2
11          Bobby_Zuko   Pistol  3000     50  161     2
10         Appa_Derren  Lookout   250     30  161     3
0       Johnny_Tsunami   Driver  1000     39  160     1
1   Michael_B._Jackson   Pistol  2500     46  160     2
2           Bobby_Zuko   Pistol  3000     50  160     2
3         Greg_Ritcher  Lookout   200     25  160     3
```

#### Input `df`:

last two rows are swapped

```
                  Name     Role  Cost  Value  
0       Johnny_Tsunami   Driver  1000     39
1   Michael_B._Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
2           Bobby_Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
3         Greg_Ritcher  Lookout   200     25
4       Johnny_Tsunami   Driver  1000     39
5   Michael_B._Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
6           Bobby_Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
7          Appa_Derren  Lookout   250     30
8          Baby_Hitsuo   Driver   950     35
9   Michael_B._Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
10         Appa_Derren  Lookout   250     30
11          Bobby_Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
```